# Looking for a word to describe a very specific feeling of surprise

Tags: single-word-requests, emotions

Recently, I had a very specific event take place (at 2AM, no less), at which time I was listening to a song (I Can't Help Myself by Four Tops) I'd just discovered. By doing this, in my head I linked this song to this event, and thus every time I listen to said song I feel a very specific emotion. Some context:

About 3 months earlier, I'd become friends with someone (who I'll call X). X and I had become close, and when talking about our families, we realised that our mothers went to the same high school in another city. We asked our mothers if they knew the other person, and we came to a shocking realisation - X's mum was my mum's bridesmaid at her wedding. Not only that, but X and I had been friends as kids, although over many years our families had slowly drifted apart.

The feeling in this moment was difficult to describe - there were elements of shock, surprise, but an incredibly positive feeling of rediscovery. A sudden need to catch up on lost years, anticipation at the fact that we were inevitably going to become even closer now that we'd realised we had a long-lost connection. It was as if we instantaneously became much deeper friends than either of us had realised - it was somewhat overwhelming. There was also a hint of sadness, like we had been missing each other this whole time, when we already had a connection. There was no animosity between our parents either, they had just drifted.

I might just be rambling, but this has been bugging me for weeks - I feel like my vocabulary is inadequate and I just HAVE to find a word (or words) to describe the way I felt - especially because I feel it again every time I hear that song.

Hopefully somebody can help me! Thanks

(This is also my first time posting so apologies if I've done anything incorrectly)

Comment: Hello, E Be. As you're asking for a single word, you need to think hard and supply a sentence with a _____ where that word would clearly fit. As it stands, 'ambivalence', 'melancholy', 'nostalgia' ... even 'synaesthesia' might be the answer you are after. Or not.

Comment: I agree it needs a bit of refinement, but it's an interesting question. *Poignant/poignancy* may apply (and is often used of reunions) but might be a bit weak/vague. Or on a completely different tack, *serendipity* refers to a coincidence that seems to have cosmic meaning.

Comment: I don't think that English has such a word, but you might be looking for something like French's "retrouvaille".